ReactJS : Refresh page navigate user to "/"
Refresh page navigate user to "/"
I have this App.tsx in which if user is not logged in and he is on privacy-policy page then if user refresh the page it directly navigate to index page ("/" route).
and could you guys please help me to reduce the logic ?
thank you in advance !

function App() {
  const Auth = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.Auth)
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState<boolean>((localStorage.getItem('uid') !== "") && (localStorage.getItem('uid') !== 'null'));

  if (localStorage.getItem('uid') && (localStorage.getItem('uid') !== "") && (localStorage.getItem('uid') !== 'null')) {
      Auth.isLogin=true;
      Auth.uid=localStorage.getItem('uid');
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Auth.isLogin && Auth.uid !== "") {
      getUserProfile(Auth.uid)
      getAllstories(Auth.uid)
      localStorage.setItem('uid', Auth.uid)
      if(localStorage.getItem('methodId')!.split('-')[0]==='phone'){
        localStorage.setItem('method','phone');
      }
      else{
        localStorage.setItem('method','email');
      }
      setIsLogin(true)
    }
    else {
      if (localStorage.getItem('uid') && (localStorage.getItem('uid') !== "") && (localStorage.getItem('uid') !== 'null')) {
        setIsLogin(true)
      }
      else {
        setIsLogin(false)
      }
    }

    const handleStorageChange = () => {
      setIsLogin((localStorage.getItem('uid') !== "") && (localStorage.getItem('uid') !== 'null'));
    };

    window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
    };
  }, [Auth.isLogin, Auth.uid]);

  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <BrowserRouter>
        {isLogin ?
          <CreateLayout>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/create" element={<Create />} />
            </Routes>
          </CreateLayout>
          :
          <Layout>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />
              <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />} />
              <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
          </Layout>
        }
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Does this answer your question? how to wait for state change of useState in reactJS to check if User is authenticated or not on Dashboard? with Context API

@AudunHilden not working

Can you edit your question to include the code from useSelector?

const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState((localStorage.getItem('uid') !== "") && (localStorage.getItem('uid') !== 'null'));
i think issue is in this logic i correct it with using   const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(!!localStorage.getItem('uid'));
but now issue is i have on login model so from that if i'm login then it is redirect on privacy policy again so it is calling Route of isLogin==true so now i think i have to redirect "/" path when isLogin is true   @AudunHilden

Do you want the user to be automatically redirected to the home("/") page when the user goes to privacy-policy or do u want, it if the user refreshes the page (from the browser manually) then it will redirect?

I want like if user goes to privacy-policy then if user refresh the page he remain on same privacy-policy page but my current code redirect user to '/'page which I don't want @SayedulKarim
